# How to eliminate render-blocking javascript and CSS in above-the-fold content in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How toeliminate render-blocking javascript and CSS in above-the-fold content in wordpress. If any one can please help me.
[image]

Comment: [Topic: Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content « WordPress.org Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/eliminate-render-blocking-javascript-and-css-in-above-the-fold-content-37/)

Comment: Few things that you can try doing are: (1) Try to combine multiple css and js files into single css and js file respectively and load that single file. (2) Load only the most important css file in the header and load the other css and js files in the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a wordpress plugin called [autoptimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/) that will do a lot of the work for you. I believe it also enables compression.  Once you install the plugin, navigate to settings => autoptimize and check optimize CSS code as well as optimize JavaScript code.

Comment: I think the basic premise is that loading an external CSS file blocks the process of turning HTML markup in to pixels.  So content that is immediately visible on your page (without scrolling down) should be styled with inline styles. With javascript, anything in a <script> tag will also blocks the rendering process.  If you load external scripts that are not essential within the first second, you could add the async option. [Here is an in-depth resource](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/)

Comment: in the rendering script there it shows the theme file the selfhosted files also as rendering blocking javascript or css

Answer (score 0):

I woudn't use a plugin.

First of all merge CSS files into one file.

Next use https://jonassebastianohlsson.com/criticalpathcssgenerator/ .

You'll get some css code - insert it inline in header.

Then you can load rest of the CSS via JS ( https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS ).

Comment: How the loading of rest CSS Via JS can be done. Do you know ?

Comment: You have to first dequeue your style (so it won't be loaded via WP) and then use loadCSS (link that I gave) to load the style you removed.

Comment: Do you have any documentation for doing this process

Comment: Not really - this is the whole proccess.

1) merge all your css into one file
2) use criticalpathcssgenerator
3) insert generated css in the header of your site (inline)
4) dequeue style with https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style
5) use loadCSS to load the CSS

It's a bit harder than installing a plugin, but within 2-3 hours you should succed :)

Answer (score 0):

Many ways. The ways to pass over 85/100 are -

1. You can use [Pagespeed module](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/)
2. Use a [third party service](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service/Deprecation) to deliver optimised frontend. [Google had such service which is closed now](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service).
3. Or follow traditional way of backend optimisation.

Nowadays, good websites pass through another service or another server as reverse proxy which automatically optimises the frontend. Thats it.

**Traditional way :**

That is one server one website and tweak on main server.

Your server's response time higher is most important. First pass it. Test on `webpagetest.org`. 
Then give priority to visible content. 
Then leverage cache. 
Render blocking matter is after making them great. 
Those optimisations are after you have passed server security, time to first byte, uptime etc.  There is no plugin that can make 100% perfect with few clicks for all sites.

You should read (see [WordPress doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style)) and load scripts asynchronously on footer or body via plugins like Header and Footer and ask on WordPress forum when you face difficult. Many times many technology websites discussed it in details. There are really very good old blog websites like CSS Tricks. You should find all articles on the topic and read from old to new. It is impossible to give an easy way. Loading Js is more complicated browser, device matter. Furthermore there is W3TC like cache plugin on normal websites.

Known problems of traditional way :

It is not odd to open up a security flaw with some snippets. With HTTP/2 push, many new things, recent security matters of WordPress during February forcing not to talk about odd plugin and snippets. None really can perform security audit. That is why [I talked about it 2 years back about render-blocking javascript and CSS, not later](https://thecustomizewindows.com/2014/03/eliminate-render-blocking-javascript-css-wordpress-reloaded/) . There I have shown settings of WordPress free Async js and css plugin. That WordPress plugin gives options for CSS, JS getting automatically loaded as inline or load asynchronously. You can try. Inline, Async all has own demerit.

It is technically difficult work than the plugins descriptions will say. Such plugins decrease the manual work but does not eliminate the need of hand coding, trial. It is part of page speed optimisation. You have to slowly learn yourself and plan according to budget.

Do at own risk at dev site with A+ score on SSL labs, add various security headers.

As you possibly a commercial website security is of more importance, followed by page loading speed.

As end tip, you should arrange to host on unmanaged server to optimise the backend. Your site is slower at present which is problem out of host.